# Deserialize simple array received over websocket in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, websocket, deserialization

I'm working on a project and I need to send simple requests from a Python backend to a JavaScript App. I have a simple array with names ["x", "y", "z"] and I send it serialized over the socket but when I receive it I don't know how to parse it in a simple array format, not JSON format.

The code should be something like this

```
websocket.onmessage = function(event){
    const receivedMessage = someParses.deserialize(format, event.data);
    console.log(receivedMessage);
}

``
```

Comment: Show us your response

Comment: Did you try `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse is for both JSON & array

for example

inputOfJsonString ='{"age":12,"name":"Mrx"}'

JSON.parse(inputOfJsonString)
=> {age: 12, name: "Mrx"}

anotherInputOfArrayString ="[12,13]"

JSON.parse(anotherInputOfArrayString)
=> [12,13]

Comment: It fails because in Python array are with simple quotes like ['x', 'y', 'z'] and I think JSON.parse can only parse the one with " " like ["x", "y", "z"]

Comment: can you send the data

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the sample serialize string you are receiving in event.data as the serialization techniques in JS may very you can use

```
JSON.parse( string, modifierfunction )
```

and depending upon the response you receive can apply a modifier function

Answer (score 0):

I used json.dumps() to format the array in python and it works now. Thanks